# "Barbellare" è un termine dialettale?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, regional

Nella commedia *Morte accidentale di un anarchico* di Dario Fo, pubblicata da Einaudi, ho letto:

> Ah sí? Quella sera il servizio meteorologico ha
>   dato per tutta l’Italia temperature da far **barbellare** un
>   orso bianco, e loro non avevano freddo, anzi... «primavera!»

Non capivo il significato del verbo "barbellare", quindi l'ho cercato in alcuni dizionari. Curiosamente, non l'ho trovato in nessuno dei dizionari italiani monolingui che ho consultato, ma il [dizionario Francese-Italiano Garzanti](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=cailler) dà "barbellare" come traduzione del francese "cailler". Poi, questo dizionario fa questo esempio:

> *ça (o on) caille ici!*, qui si gela!

Quindi, immagino che "barbellare" significhi "gelare dal freddo". È così? Si tratta di un termine dialettale?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Direi proprio di sì. Nel [dialetto del mio paese](https://web.archive.org/web/20110806011145/http://xoomer.virgilio.it/kxqjfe/dialetweb/pag2b04.htm) (zona Milano-Bergamo) *barbelà* = tremare (probabilmente derivato da *barbèla* = labbro).

Dario Fo spesso usa termini popolari milanesi nelle sue opere; si tratta di dialetto o "dialetto italianizzato".

Comment: Confermo, zona Milano-provincia

Comment: @DaG: Ecco la [voce "barbellante"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI02/00000066.jpg) su una fonte più autorevole.

Answer (score 4):

Sì.

Sul sito [dizionario-italiano](http://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?lemma=BARBELLARE100) barbellare viene definito come termine regionale lombardo per tremare, e anche sul [Corriere della Sera](http://forum.corriere.it/scioglilingua/18-11-2010/oggi-vi-voglio-escruciare-per-benino-con-il-dialetto-1661391.html):

> Tremare, battere i denti, in milanese diventa barbellà. Il barbell è
>   il mento, quindi dal tremolìo del mento per battere i denti deriva il
>   verbo barbellà. Bello, non c'è che dire. Figurato, pregno di vita e di
>   mimica, come spesso avviene con il dialetto.  Poi si verifica un
>   fenomeno curioso: dal dialetto si passa all'italiano e nasce il verbo
>   barbellare. Oggi si barbella, altro che mezze stagioni. Questo
>   ovviamente a Milano.

Comment: Quel “dizionario-italiano” non è particolarmente affidabile. Lo fa un privato, che cura anche un portale sul turismo in Grecia e un sito di ricette. La citazione dal Corriere è in realtà una lettera di un lettore a una rubrica.

Answer (score 0):

barbellàre bar|bel|là|re pronuncia: /barbelˈlare/ verbo intransitivo (AVERE) regionale nell'uso lombardo: tremare. Indicativo presente: io barbello, tu barbelli

[dizionario italiano olivetti](https://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?lemma=BARBELLARE100)

Comment: Quel dizionario non è particolarmente affidabile. Lo fa un privato, che cura anche un portale sul turismo in Grecia e un sito di ricette. E per giunta è lo stesso già citato nelle risposta presente da quattro anni.

Comment: in ogni caso confermo che è milanese. Non è lo stesso dizionario del post precedente.

Comment: Grazie. Mi riferisco al link "https://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?lemma=BARBELLARE100". È di un dilettante che ha messo insieme un dizionario dal valore discutibile.